# Inkscape XML Editor

Tags: xml, svg, styling, inkscape

I am using inkscape and a css file for styling a project. I tried to add the class attributes in the xml editor and it didn't change anything. Is there another way I could add classes effectively rather than have to manually remove style elements from the svg files? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow!  General questions about how to use software are off topic here.  You might try asking at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to add classes via the GUI is by using 'selection sets' (or by using the XML editor).

The next major Inkscape version will have better support for classes:

[image: Style dialog in Inkscape development version]